# Crosstab query with copyright year range as column heading

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have the following data that I want to create a crosstab query:

```
 ID   CallNo     CopyrightYear
 1    AH         2000
 2    AB         2000
 3    BC         2000
 4    AH         2002
 5    ZA         2005
 6    BC         2001
 7    AP         2003
```

This is the crosstab query that I currently have:

```
 TRANSFORM Count(Table1.[ID]) AS CountOfID
 SELECT Table1.[CallNo], Count(Table1.[ID]) AS [Total Of ID]
 FROM Table1
 GROUP BY Table1.[CallNo]
 PIVOT Table1.[CopyrightYear];
```

So my question is on how can I group copyright year like from 2000 to 2002 and 2003 to 2005 and so on...

Expected results:

```
CallNo      2000 to 2002    2003 to 2005
AB              1   
AH              2   
AP                              1
BC              2   
ZA                              1
```

Comment: You may want to add expected results (based on your sample data) to your post.

Comment: @PM77-1 i have edited my post to include the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer:

```
TRANSFORM Count(tab1.[ID]) AS CountOfID
SELECT tab1.[CallNo], Count(tab1.[ID]) AS [Total Of ID]
FROM tab1
GROUP BY tab1.[CallNo]
PIVOT CStr(Int(([CopyrightYear]+1)/3)*3-1)+' to '+CStr(Int(([CopyrightYear]+1)/3)*3+1);
```

In fact, you can just pivot on `Int(([CopyrightYear]+1)/3)*3-1`. The CStr conversion is mainly done for the cosmetic purposes

For the years 2000 to 2004, 2005 to 2009, etc the expression will be (note that it is value `5` for the 4 year range):

```
TRANSFORM Count(tab1.[ID]) AS CountOfID
SELECT tab1.[CallNo], Count(tab1.[ID]) AS [Total Of ID]
FROM tab1
GROUP BY tab1.[CallNo]
PIVOT CStr(Int(([CopyrightYear])/5)*5)+' to '+CStr(Int(([CopyrightYear])/5)*5+4)
```

Comment: you are welcome. Int(value/n)*n always works fine with ranges. You just need to adjust + and - parts to make it look nice

Comment: if i want to range it 4 years what value should i change? like 2000 to 2004, 2005 to 2009?

Comment: first build a simple query from this table with [CopyrightYear] and Int(([CopyrightYear]+1)/4)*4-1 alongside. Then play with -1 and +1 parts of the expression to see that the range "skips" at the right value. Once you find the "magic" numbers - build the PIVOT

Comment: basically, you need to divide by 4 and then multiply by 4

Comment: i tried many combination but i can't get it to work. can you update your answer to have a range of 4? thank you in advance

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25749/discussion-between-jaypabs-and-cha)

Comment: I hope you will help me again on my problem on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274374/crosstab-query-with-selected-range-of-copyright-year-as-column-heading

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CallNo,
CASE WHEN COUNT(Copyrightyear =>2000 AND <=2002) AS '2000 to 2002', COUNT(Copyrightyear => 2003 AND <=2005) AS '2003 to 2005'
FROM Table1
GROUP BY CallNo
```

I'm not sure if this will work.