# Crosstab query with selected range of copyright year as column heading

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, pivot-table, crosstab

This is another question that is related to my previous post at [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262565/crosstab-query-with-copyright-year-range-as-column-heading) but with different problem.

In my previous post, I ask on how I can create a crosstab query that will output a column based on 4 year range of copyright year. The answer was very good but now I am facing another challenge.

To be clear here's the data on the table:

```
ID      CallNo      CopyrightYear
1       AH          2000
2       AB          2000
3       BC          2001
4       AH          2000
5       ZA          2005
6       BC          2001
7       AP          2003
10      ZA          2006
11      DA          2009
12      DA          2010
13      RA          1999
14      WE          1997
15      HK          1996
16      AG          2011
```

Based on the previous post the sql statement should be this:

```
TRANSFORM Count(tab1.ID) AS CountOfID
SELECT tab1.CallNo, Count(tab1.ID) AS [Total Of ID]
FROM table1 AS tab1
GROUP BY tab1.CallNo
PIVOT CStr(Int(([CopyrightYear])/5)*5)+' to '+CStr(Int(([CopyrightYear])/5)*5+4);
```

And the output is:

```
CallNo  1995 to 1999    2000 to 2004    2005 to 2009    2010 to 2014
AB                          1       
AG                                                          1
AH                          2       
AP                          1       
BC                          2       
DA                                          1               1
HK          1           
RA          1           
WE          1           
ZA                                          2
```

My question is on how can I combine all the result of copyright year that is below 1999 and above 2010. A new column output that I want is like this:

```
CallNo  1999 below      2000 to 2004    2005 to 2009    2010 above
AB                          1       
AG                                                          1
AH                          2       
AP                          1       
BC                          2       
DA                                          1               1
HK          1           
RA          1           
WE          1           
ZA                                          2
```

This means that if there is a copyright year that is below 1999 like 1980 it will be counted under the column "1999 below". The same with 2010 above, if there is a copyright year like 2014, 2016 or even 2020 the value will be counted on "2010 above" column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try something else with the data provided for the pivot transformation that is more straight forward but might take more time:

create a table like that and the do a transformation:

```
+--------------+--------+------------+
| NUMOFRECORDS | CALLNO | DATERANGE  |
+--------------+--------+------------+
|            1 | AB     | 2000 2004  |
|            1 | AG     | 2010 above |
|            1 | AP     | 2000 2004  |
|            1 | DA     | 2005 2009  |
|            1 | DA     | 2010 above |
|            1 | HK     | 1999 Below |
|            1 | RA     | 1999 Below |
|            1 | WE     | 1999 Below |
|            2 | AH     | 2000 2004  |
|            2 | BC     | 2000 2004  |
|            2 | ZA     | 2005 2009  |
+--------------+--------+------------+
```

Creating the table using union query like this:

```
SELECT count(ID) AS NumOfRecords, CallNo, '1999 Below' AS DateRange
FROM table1
WHERE CopyrightYear <= DateValue('1-1-1999')
GROUP BY CallNo;

UNION
SELECT count(ID) as NumOfRecords, CallNo, '2000 2004' as DateRange
FROM table1
WHERE CopyrightYear between DateValue('1-1-2000') and DateValue('1-1-2004')
GROUP BY CallNo

UNION
SELECT count(ID) as NumOfRecords, CallNo, '2005 2009' as DateRange 
FROM table1
WHERE CopyrightYear between DateValue('1-1-2005') and DateValue('1-1-2009')
GROUP BY CallNo

UNION
SELECT count(ID) as NumOfRecords, CallNo, '2010 above' as DateRange
FROM table1
WHERE CopyrightYear >= DateValue('1-1-2010')
GROUP BY CallNo
```

The use that query for you cross tab query like that:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Query1.NumOfRecords) AS SumOfNumOfRecords
SELECT Query1.CallNo
FROM Query1
GROUP BY Query1.CallNo
PIVOT Query1.DateRange;
```

Tested on MS-Access 2010...

Comment: @jaypabs hey i have just came home and found my access installation so i played around a little and got you the full answer. it is always a good idea to prepare your data before attempting a cross tab transformation.